# How to use php class using jquery call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a problem with calling php data. Its shows me 'its works' and 'blalalala' only, without class function data. how to use class echo's calling from .load or some other way?

> php file code:

```
echo 'its works';
echo '<br>';
echo 'blalalala';
Some_Data::getData();
```

> script inside the html:

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
           function myShow(){$("#dd").load("/get_some_data.php")}
                setInterval(function(){myShow()},2000)});
    </script>

  <div id="dd"></div>
```

my program shows me this into the browser:

> ```
> its works
> blalalala
> ```
>
> So we can see that my class did not started.
>   And if i use my class without jquery its works perfect so problem not in my class. Its dont load data from my class. And even if i'm testing this case by using echo time(); as result i will see different time every 2 seconds but class do not starting.
>
> php file:

```
 class Some_Data
{
 public  static function getSomeData()
    {



      if(){         echo '<div class="my_messages">';
                    echo $row1['text'];
                    echo '</div>';


                }else{
                    echo '<div class="their_messages">';
                    echo $row1['text'];
                    echo '</div>';
                }
}}

 Some_Data::getSomeData();
```

my class and my class calling located in the same php file so with require_once html shows me all what i need... there if no problems in class file... maby its some protection moments and i need to use .get  and convert all variables into array to get them with json.parse

Comment: check the error_log if it throws an exception

Comment: class Some_Data
{
 public  static function getSomeData()
    {
       


      if(){         echo '<div class="my_messages">';
                    echo $row1['text'];
                    echo '</div>';


                }else{
                    echo '<div class="their_messages">';
                    echo $row1['text'];
                    echo '</div>';
                }
}}

 Some_Data::getSomeData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try echoing the last line as you do with the previous three. If you don't `echo` (print_r, var_dump... etc) it won't send the information to the *client*.

```
echo 'its works';
echo '<br>';
echo 'blalalala';
echo Some_Data::getData();
```

If you are already doing an `echo` in your `getData();` post your `Some_Data` class.

Comment: it works perfect if i use <div><?php
require_once 'my_file_with_php.php';
?></div>
in html
but i need to repeat my Some_Data::getData(); without reloading page
maby its impossible to get oop result with .load ? maby i need to use .get ?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know why you are using a .load(). It does seem weird. require_once should work, you can always try include_once, but I honestly don't think that is the problem. Wouldn't just echoing it from the start be more advantageous ? or using .ajax()? function?

Comment: i need to repeat result from my_file.php every 2 seconds thats why i use  setInterval(function(){myShow()},2000)});

Comment: with require_once its works indeed but we need to reload all page which is not good